# Take only a part of a MongoDB Document into a Spark Dataframe

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm holding relatively large Documents in my MongoDB, I need only a small part of the information of the Document to be loaded into a Spark Dataframe to work on. This is an example of a Document (without a lot lot more of unnecessary fields I've removed for readability of this question)

```
root
     |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
     |-- customerInfo: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- relevantField: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- relevantField_2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- situation: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- currentRank: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- customerId: integer (nullable = true)
```

What I do now is explode "customerInfo":

```
   val df = MongoSpark.load(sparksess)
    val new_df = df.withColumn("customerInfo", explode(col("customerInfo")))
                     .select(col("_id"), 
        col("customerInfo.situation").getItem(13).getField("currentRank").alias("currentRank"),
                     col("customerInfo.info.customerId"),
                     col("customerInfo.events.relevantField"),
                     col("customerInfo.events.relevantField_2"))
```

Now, to my understanding this loads the whole "customerInfo" into memory to do actions over it which is a waste of time and resources, how can I explode only the specific information I need? Thank you!

Comment: How have you verified that a lot of memory is taken? Via the Spark UI? You're not doing any Spark action, only a transformation, so nothing is actually in memory than a query plan until you collect and show the Dataframe

Comment: My action is being made at the end, when I write the Documents back to a different collection in scala after doing many transformations on it:
MongoSpark.save(final_results_df.write.mode("append"))
It seems to me that after calling that he will have to draw all the Documents into his memory and then get rid of the unnecessary "parts" of the Document as in the code above. Am I wrong?

Comment: can any one please help me on how to read the schema for above structure using pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I explode only the specific information I need?

Use [Filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/datasets-and-sql/#filters) to filter the data in MongoDB first before sending it to Spark. 
[MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala-api/) will construct an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to only send the filtered data into Spark, reducing the amount of data.

You could use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) aggregation stage to project certain fields only. See also [MongoDB Spark Connector: Filters and Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/)

Comment: I used to do that before but the thing is I need to do a full Collection Scan with around 1mil Documents and running even a simple $project aggregation pipeline on them took a very long time, even longer than in Spark.

Comment: That's separate topic that you need to look into. i) Consider adding [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) ii) Aggregation pipeline can use indexes to improve its performance during some of its stages. see [Pipeline and indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance) and [pipeline optimisation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) iii) Make sure your database resources are sufficient for the active dataset. Hope that helps.